# Javascript, subset array with more than one selecting element

Tags: javascript

How do I use an array to subset another array,
`arrayTotal` is array is the array I need to subset

```
arrayTotal = ['a','a','a','b','b','c','c','c','d','d','d','d','d']
```

`arraySelectors` is the array of search terms,

```
arraySelectors = ['a','d']
```

The output i'd like to achieve is either,

```
['a','a','a','d','d','d','d','d']
```

or

```
[0,1,2,8,9,10,11,12]
```

I know this can be done with two loops, but i'd like a more elegant option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you can use something like the array `includes` method, I would recommend using something like `Set` as it scales very well (hash table efficiency, O(1) lookup for each item). See below for an example.

```js
const arrayTotal =['a','a','a','b','b','c','c','c','d','d','d','d','d'];

arraySelectors = new Set(['a','d']);

const filtered = arrayTotal.filter(el => arraySelectors.has(el));

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Nice thinking. I'm dealing with very large arrays so it needs to be fast

Comment: Excellent! Well this approach should take one pass through each of your arrays--It will take one pass through `arraySelectors` to create the `Set` and then one pass through `arrayTotal` to do the filtering.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with a combination of `filter` and `includes`:

```
const filteredArray = arrayTotal.filter(value => arraySelectors.includes(value))
```